# How to SELECT top 3 base on an attribute value?

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a table which has 4 columns: id, student_name,phone_num, score.
And I want to select the TOP 3 student base on the score.

table:

```
id|student_name  |phone_num|score

1 | James        | 001350  | 89

2 | Roomi        | 123012  | 78

3 | Sibay        | 123012  | 65

4 | Ellae        | 123012  | 78

5 | Katee        | 123012  | 33
```

As the table shows, there are two students have the same scores.
So they are in the same rank.

I tried to use 'LIMIT' but it can only select 3 rows.

```
SELECT id,student_name,score
FROM table
GROUP BY id,student_name,score
ORDER BY score
LIMIT 3
```

Expected results:

```
id|student_name  |score

1 | James        | 89

2 | Roomi        | 78

4 | Ellae        | 78

3 | Sibay        | 65
```

Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK there is no LIMIT keyword in SQL Server. Are you sure you tagged this question correctly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll want to use a ranking function - I'd recommend Dense Rank.

```
; with CTE as 
    (Select ID, Student_Name, Score, Dense_Rank() over (order by score desc) as DR
    From Table)

Select *
from CTE
where DR <= 3
```

To expand on this function:

`Dense_Rank` will assign tied values the same number, then assign the next highest value the next highest number (in comparison to `Rank`, which will skip ranks if there are ties).  For example:

```
Value  Rank  Dense_Rank
1      1     1
3      2     2
3      2     2
7      4     3
8      5     4
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to use `DENSE_RANK` here:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id, student_name, score,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY score DESC) dr
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT id, student_name, score
FROM cte
WHERE dr <= 3
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

[image]

Another way, using a subquery to find the top 3 distinct highest scores:

```
SELECT id, student_name, score
FROM yourTable
WHERE score IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 3 score FROM yourTable ORDER BY score DESC)
ORDER BY score DESC;
```

This second approach is similar to what you were trying to do.  Here is a demo for the second query:

### Demo

Comment: Was just getting ready to post the same thing and you beat me by a few seconds :)

Comment: Yeah, I guess there is one canonical way to solve this...right down to how you alias it, haha.

Comment: Thank you, sir, both of the answers are helpful for me. But @APH answer this problem first so I mark his/her answer as accepted. Appreciate for your help!

Comment: @user8400129 No, I answered first actually :-)